# I received an email that someone created Snapchat with my e-mail - is this a known scam?

Tags: google, gmail, confidentiality, scam

On July 31 and a second time after around twelve o'clock at night (August 1) I received two E-mails, which asked me to confirm my E-mail to create an Snapchat account and the second one was stating that I "just logged in".

I clicked "If this is not your Snapchat account or you did not sign up for Snapchat, please remove your e-mail address from this account here." link , but the same day (August 1) at night I received an email stating "Welcome to Snapchat!". Then I noticed that the e-mail was with my letters but with a dot (I'm using Gmail, which ignores parsing of dots in the e-mail address). https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10313?hl=en#zippy=%2Cgetting-messages-sent-to-a-dotted-version-of-my-addre  - found this.

And tried to contact the person. And of course I got the email as well. So I tried to create a Gmail account with my letters just adding dots in between letters. No matter where and how much gmail didn't allowed me to create. So the question remains. **How did that person create Gmail with my letters and one dot in between them. How did they create Snapchat?** I tried to change Snapchat account password to delete the account, but Snapchat wrote it was invalid email.

- Did I get hacked???

Comment: Welcome to the community. Gmail ignores dots when parsing Gmail (not workplace and other domain-based E-mail services) hence you've received the E-mail sent to yourself. They created the account by using your E-mail alias.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, never click links in e-mails like this.  Go to the site URL directly.  Assuming that the e-mail is actually from Snapchat and not a phishing link, there doesn't need to be a gmail account with the dot.  A user could create a Snapchat account with your e-mail and variations with/without dots.  (It might pass their duplicate e-mail filter...)

Comment: Just in case this was a phish and that's how they were able to create the account, you should go directly to Snapchat and click on their password/account recovery link.  This should allow you to change your password and/or delete the account.  https://accounts.snapchat.com/accounts/password_reset_options